# Duplicate id of children of an element. is it good practise?

Tags: javascript, html

I have so many children, in an element, So to avoid of maintaining multiple ids, I have used same ids

```
ex
<div id="1" class="userstatus">
   <div class="floatl userdetails">
    <span id="name" class="ellips">aravi</span>
   </div>
   <div id="scode" class="status status-1"></div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="userstatus">
   <div class="floatl userdetails">
    <span id="name" class="ellips">aravi</span>
   </div>
   <div id="scode" class="status status-1"></div>
</div>
```

Here I have duplicated name, scode ids for innerElements of 1, 2. I can able to

I can able to get the name by using querySelector api. am I doing right way?

Comment: Classes are what you need. IDs are unique, duplicate IDs are wrong and should not be used.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I already mentioned, that querySelector api to find the element. So that I am asking

Comment: If you want to retrieve elements using a querySelector, you can use a particular class name and select them with `.name`, `.scode`, etc. There is never a good excuse to use duplicate IDs.

Comment: Is it good practice ? NO ! Should that be a pactice ? NEITHER. Also, although HTML5 is ok with id's being 1 single digit, I don't think it's wise to do so...

Comment: @Teemu > indeed I had overlooked that HTML 5 is more permissive. I anyway find it a bad idea to use a single number as id, but that's technically correct so I will update my remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You should never use duplicate `id`s - `id` should be unique per `document`.

If you need multiple elements with the same "tag" use `class`es.

I would recommend you read: **http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/**

#### Think of it like:

You have on your ID card an `id` number that is unique to you, no one else has it.

But you are part of the `class` of people who post Questions on SO, and obviously there are more of us.

Answer (score 0):

By definition ID's should describe one element in the DOM uniquely. Also, semantics is compromisied by using multiple ID's.